# Horizontally aligning two TextViews in Constraintlayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Helllo!

I am currently learning the basics os JAVA and I can't quite figure a little thing out...
What I want to do: Horizontally align two TextViews in a CardView, while keeping them contrained to eachother

What I have tried:

- Constraining them separately, this creates space between those two TextViews which I do not want.
- Also I have played around with Chains, but couldn't quite get it to work (doing it wrong probably).
- Lastly I tried searching this forum but could only find very big problems where mine did not fit into (relative layouts and others)

Image of the Android Editor: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcywI.jpg
The pink circle is where Im having trouble with (too much space in between)

This is the code so far I've come up with :-)

FYI: I'm following the Android Basics: User Interface and it's been fun, this just seemed a bit too advanced for them, but I'm eager to learn!

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/materialcard"
      android:layout_width="200dp"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:backgroundTint="@color/Gray200"
      app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Hi"
      style="@style/Headline1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:elevation="2dp"
      android:text="Hi"
      android:textColor="@color/Gray900"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/materialcard"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialcard" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/ExclamationMark"
      style="@style/Headline_bold"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:elevation="2dp"
      android:text="!"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialcard"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/materialcard"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Hi"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialcard" />
  
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd8Jf.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/materialcard"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Hi"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.34"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="Hi"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/materialcard"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialcard" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ExclamationMark"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.34"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:text="!"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialcard"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/materialcard"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Hi"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialcard" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

The important thing are those attributes:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
```

By doing that, now your cardView will be  be exactly 70% of the screen with and 40% of the screen hegiht.

And now if you look at the layout I have done that for the other views, allowing myself to control the space inside the cardView.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your answer.
This is a great little trick! Feels like CSS to me, which makes it easier to understand, thank you!